# Changing the colorSet of a series of a Ext.chart.series.Gauge

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

I'm working with extjs and I dont have a ton of experience with this framework. I have a gauge and I need to change its color after its initialized. In a perfect world, I would change this using

`this.myGauge.series.colorSet = ['#fff', '#ddd'];`

but colorSet is undefined in this situation.

Creating a new series and assigning it to the chart like so:

```
this.myGauge.series.add(new Ext.chart.series.Series([{
        type: 'gauge',
        field: 'value',
        donut: 30,
        colorSet: ['#aaa', '#ddd']
     }]));
```

This throws an error when it tries to redraw the chart

`TypeError: series.drawSeries is not a function`

Even though im not explicitly calling drawSeries() anywhere.

What is the best practice for modifying the colorSet of a gauge chart inside an event? The value of the gauge can change, and when it does, I need to update its color (hex codes are just test values).

```
  if (gaugeValue >= 95) {

     //Green         
     this.typicalGauge.series.colorSet = ['#fff', '#ddd'];

  } else if (gaugeValue < 95 && gaugeValue >= 85) {

     //Yellow
     this.typicalGauge.series.colorSet = ['#ccc', '#ddd'];

  } else if (gaugeValue < 85) {

     //Red
     this.typicalGauge.series.colorSet = ['#aaa', '#ddd'];

  }
```

Thanks to Eric Cook I got put on the right path. What I needed to do to change the first item in the colorSet was utilize the index variable passed into the renderer function, like so:

```
renderer: function (sprite, record, attr, index, store) {

                         var value = record.get("value");

                         var color = null;
                         if (value >= 95) {
                            color = "#1BE01B";
                         } else if (value < 85) {
                            color = "#DEE817";
                         } else {
                            color = "#E81717";
                         }
                         if (index == 0) {

                            return Ext.apply(attr, { fill: color });
                         } else {
                            return attr;
                         }

                      }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most reliable method I'm aware of is through the `renderer` function. It's not well documented in my opinion, so here's what it looks like:

```
renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store){
    // You'll probably want to set a breakpoint here just to see what values
    // you have to work with. I'm not completely sure myself.

    return Ext.apply(attr, {
        fill: "#f00" /* This is probably the property you're looking for */
    });
}
```

The Ext JS charts are still pretty buggy in my opinion, so don't be surprised if it doesn't work right off the bat. But that should hopefully get you started.

**EDIT**: The renderer is called every time the chart redraws. You can get the value from the record like this:

```
renderer: function(sprite, record, attr, index, store){
    var value = record.get("value"),
        color;
    if (value >= 95) {
        color = "#fff";
    } else if(value < 85) {
        color = "#aaa";
    } else {
        color = "#ccc";
    }
    return Ext.apply(attr, {fill: color});
}
```

I'm not sure if there's a different way to set the actual colorSet, but that's basically what you would do. Then you just redraw the chart and your colors should be changed.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use that in an event, and you were totally right about it not being documented. I've updated the original question to show how I'm using this.

Comment: thanks for your help man...but this just isn't working, the renderer doesn't even get called.

Comment: i was putting it in the wrong place! I got it calling now and changing the color, but it changes both, i only need the first color in the colorSet changed.

Comment: this was correct after all - just needed a little more in the renderer. i noticed this was being called twice, and that the index was 0 then 1. Turns out index is the index of the colorSet, so I only wanted to apply the color if index == 0, otherwise return just the attr.